# HIbernate Null Pointer bindManytoManyInverseFk

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, composite-primary-key

I have a very simple Hibernate relationship that gives me the following exception:

```
Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.
bindManytoManyInverseFk(CollectionBinder.java:1370)
```

I cannot figure out how to map this using Annotations.

Here's my code is pretty simple just 2 classes and an Id class.

PROFILE CLASS

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private int profileId;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="profile")
    @JoinTable(
        name="ProfileMetrics", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ProfileId")}
    )    
    private Set<Metrics> metrics = new HashSet<Metrics>();

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

METRICS CLASS

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MetricsPK.class)
public class Metrics implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Profile profile;

    @Id
    private String moduleId;

    @Id
    private String metricId;

    @Column
    private Integer displayOrder;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

ID CLASS

```
public class MetricsPK implements Serializable {

    private int profile;
    private String moduleId;    
    private String metricId;

    // Getters & Setters & Hashcode & Equals    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign keys have to be mapped both ways.

Inside Profile

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "profile")
private Set<Metrics> metrics = new HashSet<Metrics>();
```

Inside Metrics

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
private Profile profile;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nappa - I will try this tomorrow morning at work. So happy right now Ireland just qualified for the Euros in France!!

Comment: You were right I added that and it worked (I also had to add a int for the @Id since using JPA 1.0)  Thanks for your help!